# weak form of Sendov conjecture

Tags: cv.complex-variables, polynomials

Suppose $p$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ and all roots $z_1,\cdots,z_n $ of $p$ are inside the unit disk. Then how to show that every disk of radius $\sqrt{2}$ and centered at $z_k$ for $k=1,\cdots,n$ contains a critical point.

Comment: What makes you pick $\sqrt{2}$ here?

Comment: This feels to be strongly connected with Gauss-Lucas, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem

Comment: @PerAlexandersson AFAIK work on Sendov's conjecture is motivated by the observation that one seems to always be able to do better than Gauss-Lucas, but I don't see why G-L is more relevant to the weak version here than to the original Sendov conjecture

Comment: As a matter of fact there is way smaller bounds for the radius for instance one is $2^{1/n}$ which can be find [here](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/726/art%253A10.1007%252FBF01160464.pdf?auth66=1417558421_e78471f4e2631d315abab7cd3f2c24d6&ext=.pdf) But I am trying to come up with a simplified proof.

Comment: @BigM Can you give a link that works?  I am interested in this question.

Comment: @StevenGubkin look at T. Sheil-Small Complex Polynomials'. Section 6.4.1. Also "On a conjecture of Sendov about the critical points of a polynomial" by Bojanov et all.This [link](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01160464#page-1) should work

Comment: @StevenGubkin I think I have a proof for the weak form ,totally elementary only uses Gauss-Locus.will post it soon after proofread it.

Comment: @BigM will you please post a link to the proof?

Comment: @Liam Baker  I should have edited or deleted my earlier commnets. To this day , I have not seen a (correct) proof.sorry :-(